# How do I save phone numbers that I have received via WhatsApp to Google by default on HTC One M7?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, htc, htc-sense, google-contacts

I have factory-reset my HTC One M7 and am now running android 5.0.2 and Sense 6.0

Someone sent me a contact via Whatsapp. When I click on Save, it is saved to "Phone", and not to Google.

How do I make the phone save to Google by default?